# VIM indentation config for Javascript

Tags: javascript, vim

I'm using Vim with the vim-javascript plugin which provides the JS-specific indentation I believe. I want the following code block indented like this:

```
getFile('ABCD.txt')
.then(txt => doSomething(txt))
.catch(console.log);
```

But the plugin automatically indents it with a tab before each continuation line.

```
getFile('ABCD.txt')
    .then(txt => doSomething(txt))
    .catch(console.log)
```

Is it possible to configure so that it matches the top style? Thanks!

Comment: What did you find in the plugin's documentation?

Comment: There's a section on the docs about indentation configuration https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript#indentation-specific but none of them seem to apply to this scenario.